# my rails application not work on my debian server in production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, deployment

When I run my browser from my rails application on my debian server, the tree of my application appears in the browser.
I install and configure passenger and apache but it does not work.

Why?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You most likely have your web server pointed at `<some_path>/app` instead of `<some_path>/app/public`.

Example Apache VirtualHost:

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName www.app.com
    DocumentRoot "/var/app/current/public/"
    CustomLog /var/log/apache2/app_log combined
    ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/app_log
    <Directory /var/app/current/public>
            AllowOverride all
            Options -MultiViews
    </Directory>
    SSLEngine on

    SSLCertificateFile    /etc/ssl/certs/app.crt
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/private/app.key
    SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/ssl/certs/bundle.crt
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: RailsBaseURI /phebe
<Directory /home/.../phebee_app/public>
  Options FollowSymLinks  -MultiViews
  AllowOverride All
  Order deny,allow
  Allow from All
</Directory>

Comment: I added a redacted copy of my virtual host config above. If you are using Passenger w/Apache (mod_rails), all you need to do is point the Apache vhost at the directory and it should Rack it up automatically.